# How to echo values from unique_array?

Tags: php, arrays, echo

So I have the following PHP code for a registration form:

```
 <?php
$entries = array(
0 => $_POST['signup_username'],
1 => $_POST['signup_email'],
2 => $_POST['signup_password']);

$entries_unique = array_unique($entries);
$entries_unique_values = array_values($entries_unique);

echo " <br />".$entries_unique_values. " ";
?>
```

... And I'm realizing my echo syntax is wrong. How could I echo the different values of my array, without assigning a variable to each of my keys (there are a number of reasons as to why I can't do that)? I'd rather not use the r_print function as well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you want to output them? Comma-separated? Each on its own line? You have plenty of options. This should do the trick for comma-separated:

```
echo " <br />".implode(', ', $entries_unique). " ";
```

That said, be careful just outputting user input directly in HTML. This will leave you wide open to XSS vulnerabilities and invalid HTML in general. To output user input in HTML safely, you need to properly HTML encode the output. This would be preferable to the line above:

```
echo " <br />".implode(', ', array_map('htmlspecialchars', $entries_unique)). " ";
```

See [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode), [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map), and [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at php's [`var_export()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php).

> var_export — Outputs or returns a parsable string representation of a variable

Answer (score 0):

Try the [`implode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function:

```
echo implode(', ', array_values($entries));
```

Answer (score 0):

he foreach loop is really easy for arrays, especially single associate arrays.

```
foreach($entries_unique as $key => $value) {

echo "key: " . $key . " - value: " . $value . "<br/>";

}
```

Check out php.net: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php